# C: Not entering "for" statement inside do...while

Tags: c, loops, for-loop, do-while

I´m currently learning to program and I don´t know why my code does not enter into the for that is inside the do.

Any ideas or help would be amazingly helpful!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <string.h>  

void swap(char *num1, char *num2) {
    char temp;
    temp = *num1;
    *num1 = *num2;
    *num2 = temp;
}

int main()
{
    int l,i;
    char s[100];
    bool swapped;

    scanf("%s", s); 
    l=strlen(s);

    do
    {
        swapped = 0;
        for(i=1;i==(l-1);i++)
        {
            if(s[i-1] > s[i])
            {
                swap(&s[i-1],&s[i]);
                printf("%s\n",s);
                swapped = 1;
            }    
        }
    }while(swapped);

    // printf("%s\n",s);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You start with `i=1`, so `i==(l-1)` is true if and only if `l==2`. Perhaps you meant `i<=(l-1)`.

Comment: `i == (l-1)` would check whether `i` is _equat_ to `l-1` and wouldn't enter the loop otherwise. Is that what you need?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. It would appear that you need to learn how to use a debugger to step line-by-line through your code, which will likely allow you to easily pinpoint the nature and location of the issue you're having. Using a debugger is, for all intents and purposes, required knowledge for any programmer. For more info, see [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your comparison within the for loop is checking to see if i is equal to the characters in your string. you will only enter the for loop if this case is true.

you probably want to enter the for loop and then continue to increment i checking to see if it is less than or equal to the characters in your string.

**example code**

```
char * str = "Hello"
for(int i = 0; i <= strlen(str) - 1; i++)
{
    printf("%c", str[i]);
}
```

**expected output**

```
Hello
```